# regular expression - append increment number to each value found

Tags: regex

How do you use regular expressions to increment each find by one.

Search: `(.*)(.rar)`

Replace: `\1-#\2` <-- uncertain what replace I could use to increment it by +1

Data set

```
Hello.my.world.rar
...
Hello.my.world.rar
...
...
Hello.my.world.rar
...
```

Desired

```
Hello.my.world-1.rar
...
Hello.my.world-2.rar
...
...
Hello.my.world-#.rar
...
```

Comment: What language are you using? This isn't something you can do with regex alone. For example, in JS you can do `let i = 0; text.replace(/^(.+)\.rar$/gm, m => \`${m}-${++i}.rar\`)`.

Comment: just using a text editor with regular expression support  to do this. No language

Comment: Which editor are you using? I don't know of any that do this sort of programmatic counter stuff but I wouldn't be surprised if such a thing existed. Basically, regex can't do counting on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin in Notepad++.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `insert_num.py`):

```
import re
counter = 0
def insert_num(match):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return '-' + str(counter)

editor.rereplace(r'(?=\.rar$)', insert_num)
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> insert_num)
- Done

**Result for given example:**

```
Hello.my.world-1.rar
...
Hello.my.world-2.rar
...
...
Hello.my.world-3.rar
...
```